# How to shift popup location independent of zoom level?

Tags: openlayers

Say you have a layer with markers and an event listener that displays a popup window on mouse-over, something like

```
var hints = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(wplayer, {
  hover: true,
  eventListeners: {
    featurehighlighted: function(event) {
      var feature = event.feature;
      popup = new OpenLayers.Popup(null,
        feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat().add(3000, 3000),
        new OpenLayers.Size(200,10),
        feature.attributes.name, false, null);
      ...
```

This works so far - and `add(3000, 3000)` shifts the location alright. But I want to shift it by the same amount of pixels independently of the current zoom-level. Such that the actual marker is not blocked by the popup.

That means that I have to transform a translation like (+15px, +15px) into the current displayed openlayers coordinate system. In pseudo-code:

```
feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat().add(Pixels(15,15).toMap())
```

Any ideas how to get this done with openlayers methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are:

- [getViewPortPxFromLonLat()](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.getViewPortPxFromLonLat)
- [getLonLatFromViewPortPx()](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.getLonLatFromViewPortPx)

With these functions one can compute the translation like this:

```
var ll = feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat();
var px = map.getViewPortPxFromLonLat(ll, 72);
px = px.add(15, -15);
ll = map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(px);
...
popup = new OpenLayers.Popup(null, ll, ...);
```

Possibly, there is also a method for querying the current viewport/screen resolution (above I just use 72).

Comment: Thanks for sharing this :) By the way it works without the resolution in version 2.12.

Comment: When zoom level changes, is there a simple way to update the location of the popup? For me, this only works when first positioning the popup.